# Shake Gestures Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, storyboard, windows, shake

I am using a Shake Gestures method which was claimed to work; however it isn't on my end. Note that this method is based on the sample provided by Microsoft. The steps I followed are the following. Please can anyone help me out?

Step 1: Add reference to shake gestures library, ShakeGestures.dll

Step 2: Add a using statement to file header

```
using ShakeGestures;
```

Step 3: Register to ShakeGesture event in your intialize or activate method

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ShakeGesturesHelper.Instance.ShakeGesture += new
       EventHandler<ShakeGestureEventArgs>(Instance_ShakeGesture);

        // optional, set parameters
        ShakeGesturesHelper.Instance.MinimumRequiredMovesForShake = 2;

        // start shake detection
        ShakeGesturesHelper.Instance.Active = true;
    }
```

Step 4: implement the ShakeGesture event handler from step 3

```
private void Instance_ShakeGesture(object sender, ShakeGestureEventArgse)
{

 Storyboard1.Begin();

}
```

The End. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Does Instance_ShakeGesture get called?  ID_CAP_SENSORS cap checked in manifest file?

Comment: Well yes the ID_CAP_SENSORS cap is checked. Instance_ShakeGesture doesn't seem to be called at any point, however, the app directly crashes stating an Application_UnhandledException. Note that when I remove 'ShakeGesturesHelper.Instance.Active = true;' , the app doesnt crash but still nothing happens.

Comment: Try to add the event handler after activating the ShakeGesturesHelper. It is one of the things I have different in the project where I use the ShakeGestures Library

Comment: This didn't work either. It's still crashing.. 
Your help is appreciated!

Comment: can you put the `ShakeGesturesHelper.Instance.Active = true;` inside a try/ctach block and see if it catches an exception there and tell the exception details?

Comment: I tried this,
`try{
 // start shake detection
 ShakeGesturesHelper.Instance.Active = true;
 }
 catch (IOException e)
 {
 if (e.Source != null)
 Console.WriteLine("IOException source: {0}", e.Source);
 throw;
 }`

If this is what you meant then still it gave an unhandled exception error.

Comment: Upon several runs I am guessing that the issue is related to threads invoking in Instance_ShakeGesture function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the code-behind, worked for me.

```
using ShakeGestures;  //Add the reference

public MainPage()
{
 InitializeComponent();

 ShakeGesturesHelper.Instance.ShakeGesture += Instance_ShakeGesture; 
 ShakeGesturesHelper.Instance.MinimumRequiredMovesForShake = 10;
 ShakeGesturesHelper.Instance.Active = true;
}

void Instance_ShakeGesture(object sender, ShakeGestureEventArgs e)
{
 Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
 {

  //Perform the required tasks.
 });


}
```